# Seekbar for a mp3 file from SD card

Tags: android, sd-card, seekbar

I want add a seekbar on this class , but I cant
Please help me out

```
public class Play extends Title {  // your class name
Button button, button1, stop;
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.music); 

    TextView tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleHeading);
    tvHeading.setText("music");

  try {
        audioPlayer("/sdcard/Android" , "Lala.mp3");  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    PersianReshape.ReshapeButton(button, "2 Sfarnaz.TTF", Play.this);

     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.puse);
        PersianReshape.ReshapeButton(button1, "2 Sfarnaz.TTF", Play.this);

         stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            PersianReshape.ReshapeButton(stop, "2 Sfarnaz.TTF", Play.this);


  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mp.start();

        }
    });  

  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mp.pause();


        }
    }); 

  stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mp.setLooping(true);

        }
    });

}






public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) throws IOException{       
    if (mp != null) {
           mp.reset();     
        }

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //mp.reset();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

        }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    mp.stop();
    finish();
}}
```

I've tried a lot of code but did not receive an answer,
This code reads the file from the memory, but it is not the case for seekbar
PLZ help me

Comment: your class doesn't extend activity or fragment , why is that ?

Comment: extends Title, Title is another activity

Comment: try here http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/simple-android-mp3-media-player

Comment: No, in this class mp3 file called from raw folder, its easy. I want seekbar for s mp3 file that's playing from SD card

Comment: My question remains unanswered?